# Nesting Reactive Forms (Angular 5)

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement a nested form in Angular5. I want to divide the form into parent and many child components. I also want the submit event to be triggered differently for each individual child component.

[image]

I have attached the image as to how I want to create the form. Similar to address1, I want to create many child components with submit events carrying out different tasks.

How should I implement this form?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code to show us? Can you provide a stackblitz please.

Comment: Simply you could have he main form in a container and then pass it throughout the children as input parent like <mycomp-children [parent]="form">

Comment: TemplateDriven or ReactiveForm ?

Comment: Reactive Form @Gilsdav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to know if you want to have a form with nested elements or need to create custom form controls.

In the first case, if you want to have a form with deep nesting of elements, you just need to follow the instructions on "[Nested FormGroups](https://v5.angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#nested-formgroups)" of the Angular documentation.

In the other case it is something more complex, and personally I think it is more oriented to your need. You must create a "[Custom form control](https://alligator.io/angular/custom-form-control/)" which has its own logic and returns only the value produced by its interaction with it. Here is an example of how to implement it

Comment: Nice. I'm glad I helped you.